# How to send data to another page in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I have Main component and Bar component. I want to send some info to Bar component.*

**This is my code:**

```
render() {

<View>
  <View>
    <Bar />
  </View>


  <View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Bar', { Info:'test' }) }>
          </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
<View/>

}
```

*I cant send like this because Bar component is in this component. How Can I  fix this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your're in the same component ... `setState` is your answer

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    info: '',
  };

  render() {
    const { info } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Bar info={info} />
        </View>

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ info: 'test' });
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> State There are two types of data that control a component: props and
>   state. props are set by the parent and they are fixed throughout the
>   lifetime of a component. For data that is going to change, we have to
>   use state.

Comment: @hakan :) please take a look at this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state ... it guess it'd be helpful